# What is the difference between two condition evaluation approaches in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wonder if there is a difference between

```
if [ $x -eq $y -o $x -eq 1 ]
if [ $x -eq $y ] || [ $x -eq 1 ]
```

Both seem to work.
Thanks

Comment: That looks like || vs -o, not && vs -a. Although, the relationship is probably the same.

Comment: @Zacharee1 edited the title. OP clearly just wants to know what's yhe difference between single test with  minus  options  and two test commands

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**: they're not the same and the purpose is slightly different, although they aim at same desired effect.

The difference is in *who*  does the logic checks. As you may know, the square brackets are synonymous with `test` command. So, with `-o` you see single test command, and the two conditions are evaluated together, then returned exit status to bash.

With `&&` you have two `test` statements, each returning separately, but then bash evaluates if they are both true. The last one is recommended nowadays , since `test` is a bit dated and has issues (and new version of test `[[` is often recommended, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669486/3701431)), plus it is far more readable since the `&&` or `||` are used in many other languages including C and Java.

So in first case, with `[` you evaluate two expressions, with `&&` you evaluate exit statuses of two `[` comands.

**Additional info**:

As pointed out by @steeldriver in the comments, there is indeed built-in command `test`, which is bash's internal implementation of `/usr/bin/test`.  Regardless of this fact, the way built-in `test` and `/usr/bin/test` work syntactically is exactly the same.

Keep in mind, however, that if you're using some other shell than `bash` or Ubuntu's default shell `dash`, then you will likely be using `/usr/bin/test` . Korn shell, `ksh` for instance, doesn't have `test` built-in.

Keep in mind also the fact that `&&` and `test` are **not** equivalent:

- `test` is supposed to evaluate statements and return exit status like any other command (see [POSIX specifications for test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)). It has a whole list of things you can evaluate - existence of files, filetypes, integer and string comparison.
- Logic operators such as `&&` and `||` are used by shells to evaluate exit statuses of separate commands just like `;` does, which is one of the reasons in bash man page these operators are under `Lists` section. In addition, they cannot be a stand-alone command , like `test` - they are [standard shell list operators](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) . So, unlike `test` you cannot use `&&` to check if file exists; you can only know if command to the left exited successfully or with failure, and run or not run second command accordingly.

Comment: Isn't `test` a shell builtin in bash as well? Trying `type [` seems to indicate so. Isn't the more significant difference that `||` and `&&` are short circuit operators?

Comment: @steeldriver short-circuit evaluation isn't bash-specific, first of all.  Any implementation of logic operators does that, ever since C programming language had them.  As for `[` , there is indeed `bash` built-in for that, but depending on your system and shell you use, there might not be such built-in. Additionally, it's not the same as `&&` , i.e. they're not equivalent. `&&` is bash control operator, and can serve as list separator.  `[` is only for expressions.  In other words, what's being evaluated here is also different. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Huh? where did I imply that  short-circuit evaluation is bash-specific? or that `[` is "the same as" `&&`?

Comment: @steeldriver   So you said `Isn't the more significant difference that || and && are short circuit operators` .Technically, yes. The more significant difference is the purpose of these two things.  One is supposed to be standalone command evaluating expressions, the other is for evaluating exit statuses of commands.  As for bash-specific part, I guess I misread your comment. By the way, correct terminology isn't "short-circuit operators" ,but "control operators". Also, `test` seems not to be required by POSIX shell , because they require `test` to be standalone, so that's another difference

Comment: @steeldriver in other words , don't be confused by my comments, I meant to agree , although i didn't explicitly say so. English isn't my first language, and I'm not the most expressive person :)

Comment: No problem, nice answer btw - your English is better than many native speakers!

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see would be that the first of your command would work as a single process (`[`, AKA `test`)., while the second one may produce two processes if the first command returns non-zero.

No fundamental difference otherwise.